# Extract Substring from string using Batch

Tags: batch-file, regex-group

I need to extract substring(numeric with underscore) from a string using batch file. For example :

I have AbC_d1344_454_78a.
or
 Deg_e23_74_67.

I want to extract substring 1344_454_78 and 23_74_67.

Comment: Why you have tagged PS in this ? You are expecting a batch solution, right ?

Comment: Literally two lines of batch code to do this. Read the help for the FOR command and use the /F option.

Comment: Your first example has a trailing letter but your second does not. Are we supposed to strip off any leading or trailing alpha characters from the string?

Comment: @Squashman - If you can handle this correctly with two lines of batch code, you should post an answer. You'll have my upvote.

Comment: @Squashman There can be trailing letter. Actually I need to extract version number from file name and there can trailing character after the version number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a couple of solutions with a batch file.

If your data is always the same amount of characters before the numbers you can do a simple substring to extract part of the string. So this removes the first five characters from the string.

```
SET "VAR=AbC_d1344_454_78a"
SET "VAR=%VAR:~5%"
```

But at this point you still have the alpha character at the end. So you can do a simple findstr command to see if there is an alpha character at the end and if so you can strip it again with another substring to remove the last character.

```
SET "var=AbC_d1344_454_78a"
SET "var=%var:~5%"
echo %var%|findstr /R /I /C:"[a-z]$">nul &&SET "var=%var:~0,-1%"
```

Another option is to use the FOR /F command and take advantage of the DELIMS option to break up the string into separate variables by using the underscore as the separator.  You can get everything after the first underscore assigned to a variable like this.

```
FOR /F "TOKENS=1* DELIMS=_" %%G IN ("AbC_d1344_454_78a") DO SET "var=%%H"
```

But yet again, you now have a leading and trailing alpha character.  So again, you can use the FINDSTR command to test for that and strip the leading and/or trailing alpha character.

```
FOR /F "TOKENS=1* DELIMS=_" %%G IN ("AbC_d1344_454_78a") DO SET "var=%%H"
echo %var%|findstr /R /I /C:"^[a-z]">nul &&SET "var=%var:~1%"
echo %var%|findstr /R /I /C:"[a-z]$">nul &&SET "var=%var:~0,-1%"
```

If you have multiple leading and trailing alpha characters you can use a label and goto to keep iterating over the FINDSTR command.

```
FOR /F "TOKENS=1* DELIMS=_" %%G IN ("AbC_d1344_454_78a") DO SET "var=%%H"
:leading
echo %var%|findstr /R /I /C:"^[a-z]">nul &&(SET "var=%var:~1%" &GOTO leading)
:trailing
echo %var%|findstr /R /I /C:"[a-z]$">nul &&(SET "var=%var:~0,-1%" &GOTO trailing)
```

Interchange any of the code examples as you desire.

Comment: Simpler: `for /F "tokens=2 delims=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" %%a in ("AbC_d1344_454_78a") do echo %%a`

Comment: ... and there you go. Upvoted but I'll stick to Powershell.

Answer (score 0):

Using powershell you could use

```
$regex = [regex] '(?m)\d[\d_]*'
$matchdetails = $regex.Match("AbC_d1344_454_78a. or Deg_e23_74_67")
while ($matchdetails.Success) {
    $matchdetails.Value
    $matchdetails = $matchdetails.NextMatch()
}
```

This searches for a number followed by any number of numbers or underscores

Comment: @RandipDutta Powershell solution could also help

Comment: @RanadipDutta - No he wasn't. TheIncorrigible1 has removed the Powershell tag.

Comment: @RanadipDutta - why did you remove the powershell tag? OP clearly states that Powershell solution could also help? (did you downvote because of it?)

Comment: cause he is looking for a batch solution

Answer (score 0):

Another Powershell

```
$entries = @('AbC_d1344_454_78a', 'Deg_e23_74_67') #example
$entries | %{[System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Match($_, '(\d[\d_]+\d)').Value}
```

Depending on the formatting of the input data, you may wish to go to more or less strict regexp, e.g. `(\d[\d_]*)` or something more specific. I advice to use http://regexr.com to experiment with the regexp.